# Go http client not follow redirects

Tags: http, go

I have a function for check url like that:

```
func Checkurl(url string) {
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
resp, err := client.Get(url)
```

In error var: unexpected EOF

In tcpdump i see redirect and Connection close:

```
15:53:41.510722 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 248, id 18315, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 123)
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.80 > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.53618: Flags [F.], cksum 0xb96f (correct), seq 85:168, ack 1, win 5840, length 83: HTTP, length: 83
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Connection: close
```

How i can get Location?

Comment: What is the error from `client.Get`?

Comment: Make a new question instead of adding "UPDATE"s. Your original question is answered.

Comment: If there is an error from `client.Get`, there is no response. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Response.Location`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Location) function.

```
newUrl, err := resp.Location()
```

Type [`Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client) has support for redirection. See `CheckRedirect` field. This might be a better tool for handling redirects, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Use `client.Do` for `Request` object method

```
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
// check error
resp, err := client.Do(req)
// check error
newURL, err := resp.Location()
// check error
```

The default client handles redirections by default, therefore I would check the response of the final destination. It is most probably the root cause of your problem.

Comment: after resp, err := client.Get(url)
resp = nil
err = unexpected EOF

Comment: err in unexpected EOF after Client.Do(req)

Comment: Wget working fine:
`--2017-04-20 17:09:12--  http:/example.com
Resolving example.com... XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Connecting to example.com|XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [following]
--2017-04-20 17:09:12--  http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/
Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 42951 (42K) [text/html]`